# Can matrices be 'similar' (or conjugate) by nonzero non-invertible matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, similar-matrices

Let $A,B \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$.

> $A$ and $B$ are *similar* if there exists $P \in GL(n, \mathbb R)$ such that $AP=PB$.

While we could define something like we can define something like

> $A$ and $B$ are '*conjugate*' if there exists $P \in \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ such that $AP=PB$,

this would be kind of pointless since we could always pick $P=0$. Of course there are definitions for $A$ and $B$ to be '*conjugate in $X$*' for some $X \subseteq \mathbb R^{n \times n}$ (or $X \subseteq GL(n, \mathbb R)$) if there exists $P \in X$ such that $AP=PB$, like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2120128/are-these-matrices-conjugate-to-each-other).

Question 1: Is it possible that $AP=PB$ for some nonzero yet non-invertible $P$? I have a feeling I'm missing some obvious counterexample. If no, then please help me prove that $P$ must either be zero or invertible.

Question 2: If yes, then I have a feeling there are infinitely many such $P$'s for any given $A$ and $B$. Is it true that for every $A$ and $B$, there exists such a $P$?

- Context: Bullet 3.1 [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3544967/formula-for-anti-involutive-almost-complex-structures-and-involutive-maps-on-a)

Comment: My impression is that in linear algebra literature, people seldom write "$A$ is conjugate to $B$". When they do so, they almost always mean conjugation in a group-theoretic sense. Hence "conjugate" simply means "similar". Your definition of conjugation without requiring $P$ to be invertible seems unusual.

Comment: @user1551 I'm not actually defining it. I'm just saying that if we did do something like that, then 'this would be kind of pointless'...Or wait are you referring to the [question I linked to](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2120128/are-these-matrices-conjugate-to-each-other) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $A=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, $B=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}2&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, and $P=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\0&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, then $AP=PB$. However, $P\neq\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&0\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ and $A$ and $B$ are not similar.

Comment: José Carlos Santos, thanks. Does such a $P$ necessarily exist for every $A$ and $B$? I will edit my post to clarify that I actually intended to ask a second question.

Comment: No. If $A$ is the identity matrix and $B=2A$, then the only $P$ for which $AP=PB$ is the null matrix.

Comment: Thanks for answering both questions!

Answer (score 4):

As the other answer shows, it is possible that $AP=PB$ for some nonzero yet non-invertible $P$, and it is also possible to find matrices $A,B$ that a non-invertible, non-zero solution $P$ exists, yet no invertible solution $P$ exists.

> If yes, then I have a feeling there are infinitely many such $P$'s for any given $A$ and $B$. Is it true that for every $A$ and $B$, there exists such a $P$?

The answer is no; but we can be a bit more thorough than that.  The $P$'s that you are looking for are the solutions to the [Sylvester equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sylvester_equation)
$$
AP + P(-B) = 0.
$$
This equation will have infinitely many solutions if and only if $A$ and $B$ have a common eigenvalue. More specifically, if $\lambda \in \Bbb C$ is such that $Ax = \lambda x$ and $B^Ty = \lambda y$, then the matrix $P = xy^T$ (and its multiples) are solutions to this equation.

Of course, an invertible solution $P$ exists if and only if $A,B$ are similar. So, a necessary (but insufficient) condition for the existence of an invertible solution is that $A$ and $B$ have identical eigenvalues with identical (algebraic) multiplicites.  If all eigenvalues have multiplicity $1$, then the condition also becomes sufficient.

Comment: @John A generalization of your "non-invertible conjugacy" comes up in abstract algebra and category theory in the form of [natural transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation) as opposed to natural isomorphism.

Comment: Thanks Omnomnomnom! I have referenced your answer in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3544967/formula-for-anti-involutive-almost-complex-structures-and-involutive-maps-on-a). Please consider answering or commenting on said question in re the (homogeneous) Sylvester equation, if you think it will be helpful.

Comment: Wait it says 'A Sylvester equation has a unique solution for X exactly when there are no common eigenvalues of A and −B.' when $A$ and $-B$ have a common eigenvalue, there should be either no $P$ and infinitely many $P$'s. Why is there necessarily some $P$ when $A$ and $-B$ have a common eigenvalue please?

Comment: @JohnSmithKyon I address this in my answer.  Adapting the sentence to the wiki version: *more specifically, if $\lambda \in \Bbb C$ is such that $Ax = \lambda x$ and $B^Ty = -\lambda y$, then the matrix $P = xy^T$ (and its multiples) are solutions to this equation.*

Comment: Oh right yeah. Thanks.